# Determine what user was deleted from a security group in the audit logs

Tags: security, auditing

I have configured the site collection audit settings to monitor permission changes. In the Audit log reports->Security settings I get an excel report with Security Group Member Delete events.

The event data looks like: 645554

How do I determine what the username of the user 554 is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using SharePoint 2013, the following REST api query will do the job: `http://siteUrl/_api/web/getuserbyid(554)`